# Get the number of days from a date field to a constant date

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to get the number of days from a date field to a date that will be constant for all records but that constant date is not in the table. Here is what I tried:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_NUMBER, DATEDIFF('30-SEP-20', MATURITY_DATE)
FROM portfolio
...
```

I'm using Oracle and I am getting an invalid identifier error. I am also trying to do this without an "INSET INTO" statement.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, you can use . . . `-`:

```
select account_number, (date '2020-09-30' - maturity_date)
from portfolio;
```

Actually, `datediff()` is not available in Oracle.  I'm not sure what direction you are looking for.

Comment: All the dates in the database are in the 'dd-mmm-yy' format. That is the end date is 30-sep-20.

Comment: @nicodemusmd . . . The dates should be stored as *dates* not strings.  If not, that is the first thingy ou should fix.

Comment: Hmm, it is running now when i use DATE '30-09-20' - MATURITY_DATE. The maturity date is in the dd-mmm-yy format. Hopefully it will run correctly... Thanks for your help